# Comparing two tuples in two different file

Tags: python, tuples

I have two text file contains tuple. I'm trying match the each line with ID (basically first element is the ID). The data will be as follows:

```
Input_file_1.txt: 
('126871', 'footest', 'lolo')
('193590', 'nono', 'koko')


Input_file_2.txt: 
('126871', 'mmomo', 'qqlqlqlq')
('193591', 'Severfdfae', 'cofade complet ')



Result_file.txt
('126871', 'mmomo', 'qqlqlqlq')
```

First issue is how do I compare two tuples. Any suggestion or code sample will be gracefully appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, question updating.

Comment: How many tuples will it contain? Just two, or many more?

Comment: many more, I have read line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read from files, you can do this:

```
with open('Input_file_1.txt', 'r') as myfile1:
    tuples1 = myfile1.readlines()

with open('Input_file_2.txt', 'r') as myfile2:
    tuples2 = myfile2.readlines()
```

But as these return strings, you have to call `ast.literal_eval` to convert them to tuples:

```
import ast
tuples1 = map(ast.literal_eval, tuples1)
tuples2 = map(ast.literal_eval, tuples2)
```

Then simply:

```
for tuple2 in tuples2:
    for tuple1 in tuples1:
        if tuple1[0] == tuple2[0]:
            print tuple2
```

Which prints:

```
('126871', 'mmomo', 'qqlqlqlq')
```

Comment: Can you please explain the 2nd section of the code: map(ast.literal_eval, tuples1)
And also the way you did the third part for loop inside for loop. Few more additional comment would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: `map(ast.literal_eval, tuples1)` is identical to `[ast.literal_eval(i) for i in tuples1]`

Comment: @user2412714 The for-loop? We loop through all the tuples, and if the ID matches an ID in another tuple, we print the tuple it matches